# Slide in / Slide Out fragment animations in v21 not working properly

Tags: android, animation, fragment, slide

I run some simple slide_in and slide_out animations to open/close upon user click on any card but the animation is not working properly.

First. Slide_in animation does not slide from the right TOP corner, but rather some right-close to bottom as you can see in the images. After some time loading the contents of the fragment, suddenly it appears correctly.

Second. Slide_out does some extrange things to the previous fragment.

Here is the code for the slide_in and out:

Slide_in_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Slide in_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="-1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Slide out left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Slide out right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Here you have the screenshot of the different stages of the animation.

[State 1 - Parent fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu6FW.jpg)

[State 2 - When users clics a card... animation slide in executes but It doesn't load properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFfWe.jpg)

**EDIT1: VIDEO of what is going on:** https://youtu.be/3XtaRTqfTCk

**EDIT2: Fragments Layout**

Parent fragment layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/cc2"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header2"
            android:src="@drawable/capitalmarkets"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Child Fragment Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_100"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Into `res/animator` folder create

**fragment_slide_left_enter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="100dp" android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:duration="2500" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0.0" android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="2500"/>
</set>
```

**fragment_slide_left_exit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0dp" android:valueTo="-100dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:duration="1500" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="1.0" android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="1500" />
</set>
```

**fragment_slide_right_enter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="-100dp" android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:duration="2500" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0.0" android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="2500" />
</set>
```

**fragment_slide_right_exit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0dp" android:valueTo="100dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:duration="1500" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="1.0" android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="1500" />
</set>
```

Then in your `ActivityMain.java` use this for commit fragment:

```
Fragment fr;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fr = new YourFragment();

//Custom Animation
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                                R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                                R.animator.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                                R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit);


fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fr);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I tried it but still have a similar problem. Please check this video: https://youtu.be/3XtaRTqfTCk

Comment: I was wondering, could the problem be related with having a Collapsing Toolbar Layout?

Comment: The animation works fine, i think it is a rendering problem related to layout.. But i tried the code with collapsingToolbar and it works...show me your layout.xml

Comment: Layouts of parent and child fragments added to the question. Edit 2.

Comment: Just FYI, it works fine on an emulator running v23 and android 6.0 but the one im testing is v21 and android 5.1

Comment: You need CoordinatorLayout for AppBarLayout... Look here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout and try with coordinator layout in your fragment layout.xml

Comment: I use CoordinatorLayout, sorry but somehow stackoverflow doesn't show it, I copied again that specific part of my layout. Hope you can see it now.

Comment: Coordinator Layout as container of your fragmentlayout.xml ...sorry but now i can't edit code for you

Comment: That is what I currently have: CoordinatorLayout as a container for both fragments layouts. Please, check parent and child layouts again, i fixed Stackflow error, know you should be able to see CoordinatorLayout at the top of each fragmentlayout.

Comment: Ok but you have to close tag </CoordinatorLayout> at end of layout

Comment: Yes, I have that too, sorry but is a Stackoverflow problem that is not showing that piece of code as I pasted it.

Comment: Select it and press CTRL+K, otherwise it works?...it seems very strange with api 23 works and with 21 not...

Comment: I partially fixed by removing CoordinatorLayout from the child fragment as it is not needed adapting the layout. But I still have the same problem when going back to the parent fragment which has CoordinatoLayout.

Comment: Second video: https://youtu.be/C55bq6JIj_A as you can see, the first animation (load the child green fragment) now works due to I changed the CoordinatorLayout to a LinearLayout in the layout.xml of the child fragment. But when i clic back (second 7-8 of video) it loads back the parent fragment but it renders it incorrectly. Check the bottom of the screen is white and the top should show the action bar + the image.

Comment: @Diaviidi put your ParentClass.java